# Swift – What's wrong with this UILongPressGestureRecognizer-Code?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to move my node to the left and right when there is a long press on either side. So if there is a long press on the left side, the node moves to the left and a long press on the right side, the node moves to the right. I put this code in the `didMoveToView` but it is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
func beginTouchRecognizer(){
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longPressTouch:"))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 0
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

   self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

let WidthOfTapArea: CGFloat = 100

func longPressTouch(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = recognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
        hero.position.x -= WidthOfTapArea
    } else {
        hero.position.x += WidthOfTapArea
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check if beginTouchRecognizer gets called? If it gets called, is the view the gesture recognizer gets added to, not nil? Are touches enabled on the view? If so, does the selector get called?

Comment: I dont know what Im doing wrong. I added longPress.enabled = true and it still doesnt work. I have been trying to get this to work for the past 3 days.